# Weird Keyboard behavior when the device rotates

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uitextview, ipod-touch, uikeyboard

This is something that happens to me really often. I have a textfield in a table view cell, when I try to edit the textfield the keyboard appears, and when I rotate the device from landscape to portrait, this is what I get.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

[image: IMG_0119]

Comment: Is there something that eventually *could* be drawn where the wrong keyboard is? I.e. did you add a view in that region at all?

Comment: sorry about not to answer before, I did not get notified about your comment. And the answer to your question is: No. Check the answer, that's how I solved it. Thank you Eiko! and sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the uncountable amount of comments and answers jejejeje apparently this was my mistake.

This behavior occurs when you have a focused textField into a cell, and force table to reload using [tableView reloadData]; on a rotation event, like shouldRotateInterfaceOrientation: or didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:

hope this helps to someone.